# Regex - get URL protocol, host, path, but not filename - PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre, url-scheme

## Goal

Replace hosts and paths (locations), but keep filenames (they're unchanged).

## URL without subdomain - does not work

This works for host (domains) that are have at least one subdomain (e.g. 'www.somedomain.com'), but fails to get the path with just the domain + TLD (e.g. 'somedomain.com')

`(http[s]?:\/\/([^:\/\s]+)(\/\w+)*\/)+`

In the following HTML snippet

```
junk before tag <img src="https://somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/someimage.jpg" alt="" />Random text after
```

A PCRE engine will only capture:

```
https://somedomain.com/
```

## URL *with* subdomain - works

In the following HTML snippet (domain has a subdomain)

```
junk before tag <img src="https://www.somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/someimage.jpg" alt="" />Random text after
```

A PCRE engine captures the entire URL (save for the file):

```
https://www.somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/
```

## Question

How can I adjust the regex to capture the full protocol, domain ***and path*** (but not filename) for `img src=""` URLs that have subdomains ***as well as*** those *without* subdomains?

Comment: So in the 2nd example you want to return `www.somedomain.com`? I'm not really clear on what exactly the desired output is.

Comment: In the 1st example, I want `https://somedomain/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/`, but I'm only getting `https://somedomain/`.  2nd example is working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https?:\/\/(?:[^\/ ]*\/)*
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2DovvH/1).

**Explanation**

```
http      //Should start with http
s?        // s is optional
:\/\/     // should follow up with ://
(?:       //START Non capturing group
[^\/ ]*   //Any character but a / or a space
\/        //Ends with /
)         //END Non capturing group
*         //Repeat non-capturing group
```